# Cannot parse String to JSONArray using Gson

Tags: android

I have a mind-boggling problem.
I have the following String:

`[{"Time":0,"HR":0,"Steps":0,"Battery":0,"Screen wake":0,"Do-not-disturb":0,"Charger":0,"Notification":0},{"Time":0,"HR":0,"Steps":0,"Battery":0,"Screen wake":0,"Do-not-disturb":0,"Charger":0,"Notification":0}]`

I am trying to convert this to JSONArray in order to add more elements like this:

```
        jsonArrayData = gson.fromJson(string, JSONArray.class);
```

This is throwing error

> Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

I can get my head around what I do wrong ...

Comment: If you are using Gson, why are you trying to parse it into `JSONArray` from the `org.json` parser? Pick *one* JSON parser and use it. Create a Java class that models your HR data and have Gson parse your JSON into an `ArrayList` of that type.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it was as simple as

`jsonArrayData = new JSONArray(string);`